SF Campaign Naming Conventions for Evergreen Campaigns
I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions or best practices for campaign naming conventions when it comes to evergreen campaigns or campaigns that run beyond a single fiscal year. Currently, my company's naming conventions are:
Parent Campaigns:
COUNTRY CODE-FISCAL YEAR-NAME OF INITIATIVE-PARENT
Child Campaigns:
COUNTRY CODE-FISCAL YEAR-NAME OF INITIATIVE-MEDIUM
We have some campaigns that will run continuously, and I don't know if I should reconsider how we are naming our campaigns if some of them aren't really tied to specific fiscal years.

Omitting fiscal year from a name or having multiple years in a name is a good option.

Use a general term such as "Continuous" or "Ongoing" in place of the fiscal year
